# Jbpm 6.2.0 Could not instantiate DroolsSpringTransactionManager

Tags: java, spring, jpa, drools, jbpm

I am working on getting jbpm 6.2.0 to work with spring-boot and oracle, starting with the example from here: https://github.com/mswiderski/jbpm-examples/tree/master/spring-boot-jbpm

I hit a wall right now and get the error: **Could not instantiate DroolsSpringTransactionManager** when starting up the app. After some investigation, it seems that this is caused by a RuntimeException in the class **org.jbpm.services.task.persistence.TaskTransactionInterceptor** (in jbpm-human-task-jpa-6.2.0.Final.jar):

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not instantiate org.kie.container.spring.beans.persistence.DroolsSpringTransactionManager
    at org.jbpm.services.task.persistence.TaskTransactionInterceptor.initTransactionManager(TaskTransactionInterceptor.java:164)
    at org.jbpm.services.task.persistence.TaskTransactionInterceptor.(TaskTransactionInterceptor.java:41)
    ... 61 more

I took a look at the code in **TaskTransactionInterceptor.java** in github, the class is using a factory class called **org.drools.persistence.TransactionManagerFactory** which does not seem to exist in **drools-persistence-jpa-6.2.0.Final.jar**... I am at a lost here. Would like to know if there is a work-around or should I go back to an earlier jbpm version? Or am I doing something totally wrong?

Comment: I dig deeper into the exception by getting copies of some of the code and print out the stack traces, it turns out that all the exceptions are caused by a NPE in hibernate JTA code. I google some more and find out the cause is a missing hibernate property: hibernate.transaction.jta.platform